# A groupoid which is homotopy equivalent to $BG$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group, then its action groupoid $BG$ is a simplicial set. In fact $BG$ is the nerve of a groupoid where the set of objects is given by a point $*$ and the set of maps is given by $G$. Now assume that $G=F_{2}$, i.e. the free group on two generators $a$ and $b$. I would like to construct a simplicial set ${X}_{\bullet}$ such that

1) ${X}_{0}$ consists in two elements $*_{a}$, $*_{b}$,

2) ${X}_{1}$ is generated by the following elements:

- a $f_{a}\in\operatorname{Hom}_{X}(*_{a}, *_{a})$,
- a $f_{b}\in\operatorname{Hom}_{X}(*_{b}, *_{b})$,
- a $\gamma\in\operatorname{Hom}_{X}(*_{a}, *_{b})$,

by *generated* here I mean that each element of  $X_{1}$ can be written (not. nec. in a unique way) as a concatenation of the elements listed above.

3) $X_{\bullet}$ is a Kan complex and it is homotopy equivalent to $BF_{2}$.

Here my questions:

a) Is it possible to construct a groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ such that its nerve satisfies the above properties?

b) If not, which kind of condition should I put on $X_{2}$ (I think thai in this case $X_{\bullet}$ follows by applying the coskeleton)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X = BG \times [0; 1]$, then $\ast_a = (\ast; 0)$, $\ast_b = (\ast; 1)$, $\gamma$ is the image of $[0;1]$, $f_a$ is any choice of path in the class of $a$ and $f_b$ is any choice of path in class $b$ conjugated by $\gamma$, i.e. $\gamma \bullet b \bullet \gamma^{-1}$.

Equivalently, this is the action groupoid for the trivial action of $G$ on the unit interval $[0;1]$.

Comment: By $[0;1]$ you mean $\left\lbrace0,1\right \rbrace$?

Comment: @Cepu $[0;1]$ means the unit interval considered as a simplicial set with 2 points and one generating path between them. All other simplices are generated by the simplicial set axioms, i.e, there are 2 trivial paths and 1 inverse, and then there are higher simplices.

Comment: Ok, do you think that it is possible to construct such a retract in a discrete way, i.e for example by replacing $[0;1]$ by $\Delta[1]$+some conditions...?

Comment: @Cepu That's what I did above.

Comment: Sorry I was confused by the notation. In your construction the object is not a groupoid, but it is good enough. Thanks

Comment: @Cepu It will be a groupoid since it's a product of groupoids. If by $\Delta_1$ you mean the oriented 1-simplex, then $\Delta_1$ will not be a groupoid but its Kan completion will be equal to $[0; 1]$ above.

Comment: Sorry, here is my confusion: I though that such a retract was the following. Conisder the unit intervall groupoid equipped with 3 additional maps, one call $f_{a}$ on $*_{a}$ and the other call $f_{b}$ on $*_{b}$ and then a map $\gamma$ connecting the two points. Now consider the groupoid freely generated by these maps.  Does this give the same retract?

Comment: @Cepu It will be the same if by $\gamma$ you mean the map $\ast_a \to \ast_b$ in the unit interval. You don't need to add extra maps between those points, otherwise you would get an extra loop. Why are you calling it "retract"? A retract is a space that you retract onto, in this case $BG$, together with its inclusion-retraction maps.

Comment: Thanks really a lot! Your observation about the name "retract" is completely correct. It is not a retract but a homotopy equivalence